# Writing arbitrary many strings into one file line

Tags: python

I have a file and a list of strings I extract from the other file the amount of which may change. My question is, how in Python can I write them into the output file so that they're in one line rather than each one in new line? I tried simply using `FILENAME.write(str)` for each in a loop through the whole list but that seems to force endline after each call.

Comment: Post small parts of your files and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting them without modification will keep the newline character. Try something like,

```
FILENAME.write(str.rstrip())  # strip trailing whitespace including newline \n
```

Or if you want them separated by another delimiter you can do,

```
FILENAME.write(str.replace('\n', ', '))  # assuming one newline at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

combine them all into a single string first, and then do a single FILENAME.write with that one string.

On your list of strings, you can try using ','.join(string_list) to combine all the strings into a comma separated single string.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about it but doing so we may end up with one huge string which isn't too optimized memory-wise.